# How to initialize a dictionary of dictionary from a list and another dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list that holds x values called "states" which I use to initialize a dictionary.

```
    states_trans_prob = {states.index(s): {0: [], 1:[], 3:[], 4:[], 5:[], 6:[], 7:[], 8:[], 9:[]} for s in states}
```

As shown, the inner dictionary has 9 keys. I have another dictionary, called "actions" that has the same number of keys, therefore how can I intialize the dictionary instead of specifying it as shown above?

Comment: if the key is a number why not just use a list?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: Provide your `actions` dictionary content, please. Your question seems too vague for me and needs more explanations and/or samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    states_trans_prob = {states.index(s): {key: [] for key in actions.keys()} for s in states}
```